# 'I was trying to eat hot food, but I didn't eat the hot food'

Tags: negation, to-infinitive

> I was trying to eat hot food, but I didn't eat the hot food

Isn't it contradictory? There are 'eat' and 'didn't eat' in this structure. However, in informal, I think people use this kind of contradictions, especially when it comes to sentences including 'to's. Ex) I wanted to eat food, but I didn't eat the food. I want food when I'm in the car, but I'm not in the car.

I think 'maybe' it can be related to philosophy. Ex) Unicorns help people, but  the unicorns doesn't exist. Though I think there must be a linguistic name. After I make a picture, I describe it or after I make a statement, I make a picture, (but actually, in this case, there's no picture to referred). I want to know related linguistic terms. Something like 'top-down or bottom-up processing'

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/45478/14362

Comment: Because the attempt [to eat hot food] ***failed***, it strikes me as "marked" to describe that attempt using the continuous verb form. Far more natural than ***I was trying...*** would be Simple Past *I **tried** to do it [but was unable to do it]*.

Comment: 'I tried to do it, but I was unable to do it' totally makes sense, but I want to talk about a sentence without 'unable,' just 'but I was not to do it.'

Comment: Don't use ***try*** then. It makes no sense to say that although you tried to do something , you ***didn't*** do it for some reason other than being "unable".  You could certainly say *I **wanted** to do it but I didn't do it* even if that wasn't because you lacked the ability (perhaps you held back because you knew that doing it was morally unacceptable). But frankly I don't see how something you tried or wanted to do is a useful example context. You just seem to be asking  about "self-contradictory / paradox" utterances like *I am telling you the truth right now, by saying that I am lying*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no contradiction because you have used the word "trying".

If the sentence had been, 'I was eating hot food, but I didn't eat the hot food', that would be a contradiction.

Let's look at a particular situation.

'Someone gave me a phaal curry. I kept trying to eat the phaal, but I didn't eat the phaal because, it was too hot to keep in my mouth.'

Comment: I don't think so. 'Eat the phaal' in the former sentence has no something referred.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "has no something referred"

Comment: I mean a statement whose the meaning doesn't exist.

Comment: If you mean "'Someone gave me a phaal curry", that seems a reasonable statement to me. Or do you mean that "phaal curry" doesn't exist?   I picked it at random - it is described in this link https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/recipes/phaal-curry/

Comment: It's not a matter of reasonability. Semantically, if 'I didn't eat the phaal' is true, 'to eat the phaal' should be wrong.

Comment: It would be usual to say "...but I didn't succeed" or "didn't manage to" rather than repeat what you tried to do.

Comment: *Semantically, if 'I didn't eat the phaal' is true, 'to eat the phaal' should be wrong.*  I absolutely agree. That is exactly what I said in my answer. However "trying" to do something is not the same as doing that thing. It is possible to try, and succeed. It is also possible to try but fail. Trying is not the same as doing.  "I tried to lift the car but I did not lift the car" is a perfectly reasonable and consistent thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say:

> I trying to eat hot food, but ended up not eating it.

Or:

> I was trying to eat hot food, but ended up not wanting to eat it.

Or if you have already started eating it:

> I was trying to eat hot food, but stopped halfway through

Or:

> I was trying to eat hot food, but ended up not finishing it.

Your sentence is wrong because your using the word hot food twice.When you say what your trying to eat like "spicy noodles" spicy noodles is already your subject/object.There is no need to use it again due to the fact that 'eat' is already entitled to it and if you call ate as in "then later I ate it" the reader will know what you ate.